# how to calculate trapizoid area?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to calculate trapezoid area, what is the problem with my code? sometimes it works sometimes it gives error and sometimes it changes the result.

```
import math
def f(x):
    a=0
    b= math.log
    return math.e**x
trapizoid=(((b-a)/2)*(f(a)+f(b)))
print(trapizoid)
```

Comment: Your code is not properly formatted

Comment: your `f(x):` is very funky, can you describe what that function is meant to do?

Comment: There is a stray `'` in there.

Comment: Think about what the function inputs and outputs should be.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's as simple as:

```
import math

x = 10
y = 20
z = 15

def trap(a, b, h):
    area = ((a+b)/2)*h
    return area

print trap(x, y, z)
```

Answer given:

```
225
```

The formula for calculating a trapezoid is ((base (a) + base (b))/ 2) * height (h). You can define a function to perform this calculation, using these three inputs - that is, two bases and a height. Then when you run the function, you can plug in any variables that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let *a*, *b* are **bases** of trapezoid and *h* its **height**. Then this is the code for calculating its area

```
    trapezoid = (a + b) * h / 2
```

and - of course - you may then print it with your original command

```
    print( trapezoid )
```

If you need to write the code as a *function*, it is as simple as

```
    def trapezoid( a, b, h ):
        return (a + b) * h / 2
```

and then you may use it, e . g.

```
    print( trapezoid( 8, 6, 3) )  # The area of trapezoid with bases 8 and 6, and height 3
```